# How to lazyload external modules using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

It's able to use `externals` to use a global variable, but is it possible to lazy load the external js file on demand like what the `Code Splitting` feature does?

Answer (score 0):

You should use script loader https://github.com/ded/script.js

" Like many other script loaders, $script.js allows you to load script resources on-demand from any URL and not block other resources from loading (like CSS and images)."

```
var $script = require("scriptjs");
$script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js", function() {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a loader that allows you to expose modules from one webpack build to others via a global defined namespace, this lets you define which modules you want to share between the webpack builds and allows you to share common modules while maintaining the bundles intact.

https://github.com/MrFrankel/share-loader